# I am not able to add any atl project files in vs2015 community edition

Tags: atl

I have installed vs2015 community edition.
I can create an ATL Project but I cant add any atl project related files to my project.

When I do add item in my atl project , there is no ATL Category[image].

What am I missing in my IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Open Add Class and select ATL under category and I could see the ATL Objects.
And That's all!